# Error installing php-db in Debian 10 Buster

Tags: debian, software-installation, package-management, php

I have been tried install php-db in Debian 10 Buster, which is a dependency required by PandoraFMS Console (I'm installing it) but not working to me.

when I try to install I lack the dependency:

```
[...]
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pandorafms-console:
   pandorafms-console depends on php-db; however:
      Package php-db is not installed.
```

And if I try to install php-db manually:

```
# apt install php-db
[...]
Package php-db is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php-db' has no installation candidate
```

In packages.debian.org I can search the package and I found that:

Package php-db

```
+ jessie (oldoldstable) (php): PHP PEAR Database Abstraction Layer
  1.7.14-3: all
+ stretch (oldstable) (php): Database Abstraction Layer
  1.9.2-1: all
+ sid (unstable) (php): Database Abstraction Layer
  1.9.2-2: all
```

For more information, the content of /etc/apt/sources.list is (obviated comments):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main

deb http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
```

The directory /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ is empty.

What I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As user GAD3R points out, [`php-db` has been removed](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/php-db) due to a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=889532). The exact reasoning given here:

> - Migration status for `php-db` (- to 1.9.2-2): BLOCKED: Rejected/violates migration policy/introduces a regression
> - Issues preventing migration:
> - Updating `php-db` introduces new bugs: [#889532](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=889532)
> - Not built on buildd: arch all binaries uploaded by sathieu, a new source-only upload is needed to allow migration
>
> ....

However, you should still be able install it manually.

Download the package from [here](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/php-db), making note that you have the dependencies installed as well. (`apt install php-common php-pear`) Once downloaded you can install it with `dpkg` like so:

```
dpkg -i php-db_1.9.2-1_all.deb
```

If the package successfully installs you can use `apt-mark` to make sure that your package manager does not remove this package.

```
apt-mark hold php-db
```

If all these steps complete successfully you should be able to complete the install process for PandoraFMS.

However, there are alternatives to think about to prevent this issue. Is it possible to containerize this service? Is it possible to stay on Debian Stretch? (Which will be updated through 2022 under EOL LTS.)

Look into the bug reports and see if the regression was fixed upstream. Consider also taking the time to submit a [bug report](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting) to the Debian team if its exclusion from the repositories is a mistake.

Best of Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I too face this problem of omitted packages, There are two ways to counter this,

### 1. You can download the specific missing package.

Now this something i really hate when i go for really stable system. This has potential to break your system if you're not fully aware of your doings.

### 2. You can add the repositry of last Debian distribution which had this package.

In your scenario its says that oldstable had that package,

```
 + stretch (oldstable) (php): Database Abstraction Layer
  1.9.2-1: all
```

Why don't you append old stable repositry, just add following to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ oldstable main contrib non-free
```

Then just update and install like regular package.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install php-db && apt-mark hold php-db
```

But careful not to add unstable or testing repositries.